# How to do this using regex in python.

Tags: python

A bit confused trying to do a string match that accepts this:

Lets say a string S = "Download" Here, S can be "Download" or "DOWNLOAD" or "DoWNload". Thus, any character in the string can be an uppercase or a lowercase. Its rather easy to write a regex match for all upper case or all lower case letters or even a mix of letters, but I found it difficult to write a regex match that follows a particular order, which here is "Download".

I hope I was lucid here.

Comment: Please clarify your question with a few example of what should and shouldn't match. Are you trying to match the exact string `"Download"`? Or just the letters in the word download, in the correct order repeated any number of times? Or are you trying to check if the word `"Download"` appears in a larger string? And are you trying to do a case-sensitive match?

Answer (score 6):

To check if `"download"` appears in a string regardless of case, you don't even need a regular expression.

```
"download" in s.lower()
```

will also work fine.

Comment: What if he really wants to match something? e.g. `this` in a string `'Download this'`.

Comment: @rplnt: I don't get it: `'this' in 'Download this'`

Comment: @katrielalex `re.findall(r'Download (\w+)', 'download this or download that')` for example. Op could've simplified his problem to one thing he had problem with.

Comment: @katrielatex that fails on input like "I like thistles a lot" -- 'this' is in there, but (maybe?) a false match in reality.

Answer (score 5):

First, you can covert the string before the match

```
re.search(expr, s.lower())
```

If you want to ingore the case, you can use flag `re.IGNORECASE`

```
re.search(expr, s, re.IGNORECASE)
```

See other available flags here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-contents

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with: `S == "Download"` ?

Your question isn't clear about whether you want to ignore case or not.

`"I found it difficult to write a regex match that follows a particular order"`

A particular order of capitalisation or just a particular order of letters?

If you want to ignore case, just convert to lower-case before comparing:

```
S.lower() == "download"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s="Download"
re.findall("^[A-Z][a-z]*$",s)
['Download']
s="DownloaD"
re.findall("^[A-Z][a-z]*$",s)
[]
s="download"
re.findall("^[A-Z][a-z]*$",s)
[]
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to match a string with the First Cap followed by small case. In such a scenario, the above should work.

Comment: In case the string is not a complete sentence, you can write `re.findall("(^[A-Z][a-z]*)[^a-z]?",s)`  and if its not the beginning of the string `re.findall("([A-Z][a-z]*)[^a-z]?",s)`

Comment: I'm talking about a perfect match. This is generic, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: By perfect match you mean, it will match only `"Download"` and nothing else, in that case what's wrong in `s=="Download"`. Or is it like, you wan't to see if "Download" is present in the string or not. Is it like you want to search `.*Download.*`. Please clarify